# How to fix Fishdom loading in Nox Player (app management)?

Tags: google-play-services, noxplayer

I get a Fishdom not responding error (from the very first time) every time when loading. According to the internet, the solution is to clear the App's cache and activate Force Stop on Android system but I can't find an equivalent on Nox Player. Neither can I find out how uninstall to try reinstalling it. How do I fix Fishdom on Nox Player?

Comment: Fishdom is a game

Comment: Apps can be uninstalled in any Android version I know by opening Android settings (the gear icon) -> Applications -> app list -> select an entry and get the app info page where you can delete app data or uninstall it.

Answer (score 1):

The process of uninstalling an app on any Android device is nearly the same.

- Open **Settings**.
- Tap on **Apps**.
- Select See all apps.
- **Find the app you want** to remove and select it.
- Tap **Uninstall**.
- Click OK.

Reinstall the game from the Play store, if it still doesn't open, you can download the **BlueStacks** emulator instead.

Comment: Its Android Emulator. BlueStacks is total broken.

Comment: Nox Player is also an android emulator, btw BlueStacks was the smoothest emulator I've used.